# Trying to stop pygame but it can't because of interrupt

Tags: python, moviepy, psutil

So I want it so when you click the x button on the top it stops the whole process but there is this "interrupt" error I keep getting and I tried multiple ways to stop the video, pygame or audio and none of them work. It just keeps printing in console interrupt.

```
import random
import psutil
import sys

from pygame.locals import *
from moviepy.editor import *
from pypresence import Presence
import time

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('lofi hip hop radio - beats to relax/study to - v1.0')

 
def launch(movie):
    clip = VideoFileClip(movie)
    clip.preview()

def checkIfProcessRunning(processName):
    '''
    Check if there is any running process that contains the given name processName.
    '''
    #Iterate over the all the running process
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            # Check if process name contains the given name string.
            if processName.lower() in proc.name().lower():
                return True
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
    return False;

def repeat():
    running = True

    clip = VideoFileClip("lofivid1.mp4")
    time.sleep(5)
    randomNumber = random.randint(1, 2)
    print(str(randomNumber))
    pygame.mixer.music.load("song" + str(randomNumber) + ".wav")
    pygame.mixer.music.play() 
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() and running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
    
        if(running):
            clip.preview()
        else:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
    

while 1:
    if checkIfProcessRunning('discord'):
        client_id = 'ID CLIENT' #Put your client ID here
        RPC = Presence(client_id) 
        RPC.connect() 
        print(RPC.update(state="Listening", details="Doing homework", large_image="https://static.actu.fr/uploads/2020/04/maxresdefault-960x640.jpg", small_image="https://static.actu.fr/uploads/2020/04/maxresdefault-960x640.jpg", large_text="LofiCli", start=time.time()))
    else:
        pass

    repeat()
```

Every-time you click the x button you get this printed in console

```
Interrupt
```

And it does not close or change anything

Comment: What is the full error you get, including the stack trace? Please edit it into your question.

Comment: You imported sys, but didn't use it. Do sys.exit() rather than exit()